# ASP .NET Core Custom Authorize Attribute for viewing users own data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, authorization, custom-attributes

Scenario: User1 with "View" permissions can see all other user profiles in a list and when they click on a profile they will be directed to that profile page.

User2 with no permissions can see a list of user profiles but can only click on their own profile to view otherwise they are redirected to forbidden.

Not sure of the best method to implement this Authorization check. Currently trying to use the answer from this question: [Adding .Net Core Policy with variable Parameters on Requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58859199/adding-net-core-policy-with-variable-parameters-on-requirements)

but I don't know how I could send the id parameter from this controller method and also check first if the user does have the "View" permission

```
[HttpGet("{id:int:min(1)}")]
[CustomAuthorizeAttribute(id)] // doesnt work
public async Task<ActionResult> GetUser(int id)
```

Answer (score 0):

In that solution, The parameter is a certain value in development, not obtained from routing. `[CustomAuthorizeAttribute(id)]` is scanned when project starts, it is different form the `[HttpGet("{id:int:min(1)}")]`.

In this scenario, I think you don't need to define the `CustomAuthorizeAttribute`. If one user can view all the profiles, the user need to be added the claim `View` when generating token.

```
new Claim("Permission", "View")
```

When in GetUser, you only need to judge whether the user has the claim.

```
    [HttpGet("{id:int:min(1)}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetUser(int id)
    {
        if(User.Claims.Contains(new Claim("Permission", "View")))
        {
            //...
            return View();
        }else if(User.Claims.Contains(new Claim("id", id.ToString())))
        {
            //own id can view own profile
            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            return Forbid();
        }
    }
```